# Emulate public/private properties with __get() and __set()?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

I was writing a class that uses `__get()` and `__set()` to store and retrieve array elements in a master array. I had a check to make some elements ungettable, basically to re-create private properties.

I noticed that it seemed that `__get` intercepts all calls to class properties. This sucks for me, because I wanted to have a variable private to the outside world ( unavailable via get ), but I was trying to access it by directly referencing the master array from within the class. Of course, the master array is not in the whitelist of gettable properties :(

Is there a way I can emulate public and private properties in a php class that uses `__get()` and `__set()`?

Example:

```
<?
abstract class abstraction {

    private $arrSettables;
    private $arrGettables;
    private $arrPropertyValues;
    private $arrProperties;

    private $blnExists = FALSE;

    public function __construct( $arrPropertyValues, $arrSettables, $arrGettables ) {

        $this->arrProperties = array_keys($arrPropertyValues);
        $this->arrPropertyValues = $arrPropertyValues;
        $this->arrSettables = $arrSettables;
        $this->arrGettables = $arrGettables;
    }

    public function __get( $var ) {
        echo "__get()ing:\n";
        if ( ! in_array($var, $this->arrGettables) ) {
            throw new Exception("$var is not accessible.");
        }

        return $this->arrPropertyValues[$var];
    }

    public function __set( $val, $var ) {
        echo "__set()ing:\n";
        if ( ! in_array($this->arrSettables, $var) ) {
            throw new Exception("$var is not settable.");
        }

        return $this->arrPropertyValues[$var];
    }

} // end class declaration

class concrete extends abstraction {

    public function __construct( $arrPropertyValues, $arrSettables, $arrGettables ) {
        parent::__construct( $arrPropertyValues, $arrSettables, $arrGettables );
    }

    public function runTest() {

        echo "Accessing array directly:\n";
        $this->arrPropertyValues['color'] = "red";
        echo "Color is {$this->arrPropertyValues['color']}.\n";

        echo "Referencing property:\n";
        echo "Color is {$this->color}.\n";
        $this->color = "blue";
        echo "Color is {$this->color}.\n";

        $rand = "a" . mt_rand(0,10000000);
        $this->$rand = "Here is a random value";
        echo "'$rand' is {$this->$rand}.\n";

    }
}

try {
    $objBlock = & new concrete( array("color"=>"green"), array("color"),  array("color") );
    $objBlock->runTest();
} catch ( exception $e ) {
    echo "Caught Exeption $e./n/n";
}

// no terminating delimiter

$ php test.php
Accessing array directly:
__get()ing:
Caught Exeption exception 'Exception' with message 'arrPropertyValues is not accessible.' in /var/www/test.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/test.php(50): abstraction->__get('arrPropertyValu...')
#1 /var/www//test.php(68): concrete->runTest()
#2 {main}.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can emulate public and private properties in a php class that uses __get() and __set()?

Not directly (if you discount [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace)).

But you can have a private method `getPriv` that does all the work your current `__get` does. Then `__get` would only wrap this private method and check accessibility.

```
function __get($name) {        
    if (in_array($name, $this->privateProperties))
        throw new Exception("The property ". __CLASS__ . "::$name is private.");
    return $this->getPriv($name);
}
```

Inside your class, you would call `getPriv`, thus bypassing `__get`.

Comment: But there's still a problem -- since I'm storing everything in an array, `getPriv()` has to reference the value in the class property `$arrPropertyValues`, which is intercepted by `__get()`... infinite loop?

Comment: I'll be darned! It works! But why? Is it because `__get()` doesn't intercept in the originating class?

Comment: @user It does intercept in the originating class – hence inside the class you should call `getPriv`. I'm not sure I understood you, but `__get` does not intercept method calls or property access if the properties are explicitly declared.

Comment: Oh now I see. I was confused -- I thought `getPriv()`'s reference to `$arrPropertyvalues[$var]` would be intercepted by `__get()`, but since it `$arrPropertyValues` is declared, it's not intercepted. Right?

Comment: BTW I meant to upvote you but I mucked it up when I undid the upvote when I thought there would be an infinite loop.

Comment: @user Well, you can now; I've edited the question :p And yes, that's it.

Comment: BTW, what's the `debug_backtrace` method?

Answer (score 1):

Make `abstraction::$arrPropertyValues` protected or do what Artefacto wrote (if you need additional checks), except that `abstraction::getPriv()` should be protected.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manually enlisting private/protected properties, you could use PHPs cumbersome reflection methods:

```
function __get($name) {

    $reflect = new ReflectionObject($this);
    $publics = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

    if (in_array($name, $publics)) {
         return $this->{$name};
    }
}
```