# PHP properties with get/set functions

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, magic-methods

One of the handy features of other languages is the ability to create get and set methods for properties.  In trying to find a good way to duplicate this functionality in PHP, I stumbled across this:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#98442

Here is my breakdown of that class:

```
<?php

class ObjectWithGetSetProperties {

    public function __get($varName) {
        if (method_exists($this,$MethodName='get_'.$varName)) {
            return $this->$MethodName();
        } else {
            trigger_error($varName.' is not avaliable .',E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    public function __set($varName,$value) {
        if (method_exists($this,$MethodName='set_'.$varName)) {
            return $this->$MethodName($value);
        } else {
            trigger_error($varName.' is not avaliable .',E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

My plan was to extend this class and define the appropriate `get_someproperty()` and `set_someproperty()` in this extended class.

```
<?php
class SomeNewClass extends ObjectWithGetSetProperties {
    protected $_someproperty;
    public function get_someproperty() {
        return $this->_someproperty;
    }
}
?>
```

The trouble is, the base class of `ObjectWithGetSetProperties` is unable to see my method `get_someproperty()` in `SomeNewClass`.  I always get the error, "key is not available".

Is there any way to resolve this, allowing the base class of `ObjectWithGetSetProperties` to work, or will I have to create those `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods in each class?

Comment: Similar to what I am trying to accomplish, but not quite:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479036/emulate-public-private-properties-with-get-and-set

Comment: Not to malign your question (it's a sensible API goal), but consider [Why getter and setter methods are evil](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html) for stylistic reasons. (interesting read even if not applicable)

Comment: @mario, I will read it more in-depth another day, but I don't think the arguments in that article are applicable for the kind of class I am building.  I am building a class to represent data.  In fact, it will do very little.  Its primary purpose is to represent something in the real world with a series of properties.  None the less, I will read that article more thoroughly later, and perhaps post a new question about it on SO.

Comment: @mario Interesting read indeed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`is_callable`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) instead.  Example code-fragment:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Edmonton");
class A {
    protected $_two="goodbye";
    protected $_three="bye";
    protected $_four="adios";
    public function __get($name) {
        if (is_callable(array($this,$m="get_$name"))) {
            return $this->$m();
        }
        trigger_error("Doh $name not found.");
    }
    public function get_two() {
        return $this->_two;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    protected $_one="hello";
    protected $_two="hi";
    protected $_three="hola";
    public function get_one() {
        return $this->_one;
    }
    public function get_two() {
        return $this->_two;
    }
    public function get_three() {
        return $this->_three;
    }
    public function get_four() {
        return $this->_four;
    }
}

$a=new a();
echo $a->one."<br />";//Doh one not found.
echo $a->two."<br />";//goodbye
echo $a->three."<br />";//Doh three not found.
echo $a->four."<br />";//Doh four not found.
$b=new b();
echo $b->one."<br />";//hello
echo $b->two."<br />";//hi
echo $b->three."<br />";//hola
echo $b->four."<br />";//adios
?>
```

(Updated to show where `B` overrides `A`)

Answer (score 3):

That's not well documented (some mentions in the [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)), but `method_exists()` really only checks for method presence in the current class.

But you can use `is_callable()` instead. It also verifies that the method not only exists, but is indeed allowed to be invoked:

```
 if (  is_callable(array($this, $varName))  ) {
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you'll need to declare the `$_someproperty` property, like this

```
class SomeNewClass extends ObjectWithGetSetProperties {
    protected $_someproperty;
    public function get_someproperty() {
        return $this->_someproperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, this was an absent-minded omission in my example.  I will fix it, but is not the source of my problem.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  id="fname" method="post">
    <textarea name="sms" id="messageText"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="smsbut"  value="sms"/>
</form> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fname").submit(function()
        {
            var sms = $('#messageText').val();
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "sms.php/?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>",
                        data: {userSms: sms},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(result)
                        {
                            if (result["error"] != undefined)
                            {

                            }
                            else if (result["success"] != undefined)
                            {
                                $('#messageText').val("");
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```